# Why does std::vector fill constructor not enable emplacement?

Tags: c++11, vector, move-semantics

Every now and then I come across a situation when I need to create an array of non-copy-constructible objects.  For example:

```
std::vector<std::thread> thread_pool(NUM_CORES, std::thread(some_function));
```

That would be convenient.  But alas, the `std::vector` fill constructor doesn't seem to have any support for R-values.  It is defined as:

```
 vector( 
         size_type count, 
         const T& value,
         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()
 );
```

But it would be *extremely convenient* to have:

```
 vector( 
         size_type count, 
         T&& value,
         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()
 );
```

Then the vector could internally allocate the necessary buffer size, and move-construct each element with placement new.

But... the C++11 standard (and apparently even the C++14 standard) don't provide this capability.  So, now - when I have a vector of threads, I have to say:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> thread_pool(NUM_CORES);
/* now loop over vector and initialize elements one by one */
```

Is there some reason this ability was left out?  Is there some danger?  Or some problem that I'm not seeing?

Comment: A way better "workaround" would be `std::vector<std::thread> v; v.reserve(NUM_CORES); for ( ... ) v.emplace_back(...);`. No need for pointers. The answer is probably "because no one ever bothered to propose this".

Comment: After a move construct or assignment, the rvalue reference is left in a valid but unknown state. What you would really wants is to be able to have a variadic constructor like emplace_back. But the rvalue thing raise again if any of the T constructor arguments are rvalues. The @stefan workaround is what i usually do.

Comment: Lol how do you propose to move-construct multiple elements from one original argument?

Comment: Right... yeah, sorry - that should have been obvious.  Anyone who wants to write this answer I'll accept, otherwise I'll delete the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you propose is not feasible because, by its very nature, *moving* is the transfer of a state from **one** object to **one** other object. You cannot construct *N* objects by moving state from one to all of them at the same time.

The Stargate universe violated this rule by introducing the ability to open a wormhole to every gate in the galaxy simultaneously, which made no sense at all and really annoyed me. Don't be that guy!

A vector constructor looking like this:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename Args...>
std::vector<T>::vector(const size_t n, Args&&... args);
```

…following the `emplace` model *could* work, though I worry that it would be easy to get an ambiguous overload thanks to the sheer number of existing constructors for `std::vector<T>`. I suspect this is why it was not done, besides the fact that it isn't really necessary.

Because, for now, you can workaround it by emplacing one at a time which, regardless, is probably as performant as you can ever hope to get:

```
std::vector<std::thread> v;
v.reserve(NUM_CORES);
for ( /*...*/ )
   v.emplace_back( /*...*/ );
```